# Flask application cannot be exposed on droplet

Tags: python, flask, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a flask server to a Digital Ocean droplet.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/a/<string:b>")
def deploy(b):
    return "Response"
```

Using the following command:

```
FLASK_APP=server.py python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5555
```

When I deploy the application locally, I can receive response by doing

```
curl -XGET localhost:5555/a/random
```

When deploying on the droplet, it works internally, but when calling the droplet externally (despite having exposed port 5555 on TCP) it does not connect.

What could have changed? I'm also deploying a flask graphql server on the same droplet via docker which works perfectly fine.

Comment: What command did you use to expose the 5555/tcp port?

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -nltp` ? Do you have the DigitalOcean firewall enabled or run e.g. ufw on the droplet? If yes, what's the output of `ufw status` ?

Comment: I’ve exposed the port via the web interface. This same approach worked for the flask_graphql server on a different port. I will run the commands you suggest and report back later!

Comment: This is the output from netstat:

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3971/python3

Comment: @Oliver - see above for netstat output

Comment: You mentioned the other deploy you did in the same droplet was using docker. Is this deploy also using docker? If so, did you remember to map the port in the container?

Comment: It's not using docker, it's directly exposed on localhost.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible a common issue when uses VPS.
People like me may often forget to setup **firewall**(s) if the codes are correct.

You mentioned that it works locally but not externally. I guess it should be.

Digital Ocean level:

- Add inbound TCP port 5555 in droplet firewall setting

System level

- iptables: e.g. `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -dport 5555 -j ACCEPT`
- firewalld: e.g. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5555/tcp`

Or you may disable OS firewalls by `systemctl stop [service-name]` or `service [service-name] stop`. You may google the commands.

Comment: I have set up the firewalls in Digital Ocean. When using Docker, there was no need to enable additional firewalls on the machine, can you confirm this is needed in addition to the docker set-up?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure whether docker need to setup firewalls on host machine. I remember that docker will create an bridge adapter for connections. But I did not dig into it to see if it need firewall setting. 

Besides, "docker start" need "-p 5555:5555" argument to map container port to host port.

Comment: I checked this articlle [ https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ ]. It looks docker will automatically add rules to iptables so that user no need to add rules by self. And for other OS level firewalls such as firewalld and etc, I am not sure if docker can automatically setup the rules. But on Digital Ocean level, I guess you still need to open the port so that the traffic may like this : "container port 5555" -> "host port 5555" -> "digital ocean firewall 5555"

Comment: fix an issue. I mentioned "docker start", it should be "docker run"

Comment: From this "I'm also deploying a flask graphql server on the same droplet via docker which works perfectly fine.", I think that you opened the port on Digital Ocean but not in system firewall(s). As docker will automatically add rules to iptables, It can works. Without docker, the port is not opened. We can have a try to simply disable system firewalls to check if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Flask accepts connections from localhost by default.

In order to make your Flask app publicly available, you have to bind it to 0.0.0.0 address by adding `--host=0.0.0.0` parameter.

> **Externally Visible Server**
>
> If you run the server you will notice that
> the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any
> other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a
> user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your
> computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
> you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
> --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0 This tells your operating system to listen on
> all public IPs.